# If statement - 'or' but NOT 'and'

Tags: c#, if-statement

In C Sharp, how can I set up an if statement that checks if one of several conditions is true? It must be only one of the conditions, if zero or two or more are true the if should be false.

Comment: @Tim S. It's quite uncouth to enter your answer in the comments of several different other answers.  Delete those comments and post your answer as an answer and accept judgement of it from voting - as Jeff intended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write a helper method. This has the advantage that it short circuits, only evaluating exactly as many as necessary,

```
public static bool IsExactlyOneTrue(IEnumerable<Func<bool>> conditions) {
    bool any = false;
    foreach (var condition in conditions) {
        bool result = condition();
        if (any && result) {
            return false;
        }
        any = any | result;
    }
    return any;
}
```

Comment: This method can be simplified to `return !conditions.Where(cond => cond()).Skip(1).Any();`  It's only arguably more readable, and it might run a hair slower, but unless this is actually found to be significant, I'd go for the more concise one.

Comment: On further looking, this has to be more like this to work right: `var trueConditions = conditions.Where(cond => cond());
            if (!trueConditions.Take(1).Any())
                return false;
            return !trueConditions.Skip(1).Any();`  I'm starting to like your answer better than my LINQ approach.

Comment: @TimS.: But that may cause the leading false-resulting expressions to be evaluated twice. I don’t think there’s any elegant way of doing it in LINQ (except by projecting indexes, which defeats the whole purpose).

Comment: Indeed.  I just tested it with a false, and then true expression, and it evaluates each twice.  It might be fixable, but with more and more complexity that far outweighs Jason's solution.  LINQ just isn't made to handle such a situation well.

Comment: @TimS.: I experimented a bit more, and found that it may be done elegantly in LINQ if one assumes the existence of a predicate-based `IndexOf` operator (which can be easily defined). See my edited answer below.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I might have been able to solve this using LINQ, but it just doesn't work well.

Answer (score 5):

You could use compose your booleans into a `bool` sequence and then apply LINQ:

```
bool[] conditions = new bool[] { cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4 };
bool singleTrue = conditions.Count(cond => cond) == 1;
```

For just two booleans, exclusive or becomes much simpler:

```
bool singleTrue = cond1 != cond2;
```

**Edit**: To achieve on-demand evaluation *and* short-circuiting, we need to promote our `bool` sequence into a `Func<bool>` sequence (where each element is a function delegate encapsulating the evaluation of a condition):

```
IEnumerable<Func<bool>> conditions = // define sequence here
int firstTrue = conditions.IndexOf(cond => cond());
bool singleTrue = firstTrue != -1 && 
                  conditions.Skip(firstTrue + 1).All(cond => !cond());
```

The above snippet assumes the existence of a predicate-based `IndexOf` operator, which is not available under the current version of LINQ but may be defined as an extension method like so:

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
            return i;

        i++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Sample data for testing (a breakpoint may be set on each `false` or `true` to follow evaluation):

```
IEnumerable<Func<bool>> conditions = new Func<bool>[] 
{ 
    () => 
        false,
    () => 
        true,
    () => 
        false,
    () => 
        false,
};
```

Comment: This has the weakness that it is necessary to evaluate all of the conditions.

Comment: That can be fixed by changing it to a `Func<bool>[]` and using `conditions.Where(cond => cond()).Skip(1).Any();`.

Comment: @TimS.: Wouldn’t `Skip(1)` fail when all values are false?

Comment: Hm...it won't "fail" as in throw, but it doesn't quite behave right - it returns true.

Comment: I've posted a revision in my comment to Jason's answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
List<Func<Customer, bool>> criteria = new List<Func<Customer, bool>>();

criteria.Add(c => c.Name.StartsWith("B"));
criteria.Add(c => c.Job == Jobs.Plumber);
criteria.Add(c => c.IsExcellent);

Customer myCustomer = GetCustomer();

int criteriaCount = criteria
  .Where(q => q(myCustomer))
  // .Take(2)  // optimization
  .Count()
if (criteriaCount == 1)
{
}
```

---

Linq implementation of Jason's method signature:

```
public static bool IsExactlyOneTrue(IEnumerable<Func<bool>> conditions)
{
  int passingConditions = conditions
    .Where(x => x())
    // .Take(2) //optimization
    .Count();
  return passingConditions == 1;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Can also do it without relationship to a specific type: `var conditions = new List<Func<bool>>();
            conditions.Add(() => foo == bar);
            if (conditions.Select(x => x.Invoke()).Count(x => x) == 1) { }`

Comment: Sure, you're just shoving the specific instances into the criteria.  My "criteria" collection delays the need to have an applicable instance and is re-usable for as many instances as you have.

Comment: This approach requires evaluating all of the conditions, whether or not it is necessary. I prefer an approach that permits short circuiting.

Comment: No.  Just uncomment the Take and execution will stop at the first moment it can.

Comment: @David B: The `Take` isn't uncommented, now, is it?

Answer (score 4):

Going for simplicity, you could just keep a running count:

```
int totalTrue = 0;
if (A) totalTrue++;
if (B) totalTrue++;
if (C) totalTrue++;
...
return (1 == totalTrue);
```

Comment: Personally I'd write that last statement as `return totalTrue == 1;`. I understand the rationale for writing such tests backwards, but I disagree with it -- and the parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I just want to keep myself in the habit of writing code in that order in case I ever go back to C++.

Comment: @Adam V: When in Rome, do as the Romans do. C# and C++ are not the same language. Don't write C# in C++, and C++ in C#.

Comment: @AdamV: Why does it make any more sense in C++ than in C#? Both use `=` for assignment and `==` for equality. (Personally, I just find things like `if (x ==1)` jarring.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: In C++ the line `if (x = 1)` will set `x` to 1 and treat it as `true`, causing you to enter the `if` block. In C# the line won't compile because it doesn't treat it as `true`.

Comment: @Jason: if it were invalid code, or code that changed meaning between languages, I'd agree with you. But since it's just a habit, I'll keep it.

Comment: @Adam V: Here's the thing. When a C# programmer reads C# code, they expect to see C# written in C#. There are idioms in the language, and code that goes against those idioms is a distraction.

Comment: In any case, the parentheses are superfluous in either language.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would do the trick

```
 int i= 0;
 if ( (!A || ++i <= 1) && 
      (!B || ++i <= 1) && 
      (!C || ++i <= 1) && 
      ... && 
      (i == 1))
```

If I didn't think wrong on this, this `if` will be false as soon as `i > 1`. If `i` is never incremented and we reach the last condion, will be false since `i == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers will work and have 'good performance'. But the simplest answer is:

```
if( (A & !(B || C)) || 
    (B & !(A || C)) ||
    (C & !(A || B)) )
{
   ...
}
```

You do end up evaluating A/B/C more than once so this is really only useful when you have simple bools.